# How to Bulk Edit M-values in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Let's say I have a line with a default M value set for all vertices. I'd like to apply some function to edit or replace those values. Is there any way to do that?

You can manually edit the M values in the vertex editor but I don't see any built-in functions for that.

Update 6/26/2023:

As mentioned in a comment, the purpose here is to generate a random variable width river polygon from a line using Buffer by M and randomly assigned M values. Attempting to use setM() as recommended but it doesn't appear to stick.

Simple example: a line layer with a 2-vertex line with m-values assigned as 1 and 2, respectively. The log shows the m-values updating, but when I then run the "buffer by m" function, it uses the original m-values of 1 and 2, not the newly assigned ones. It's probably a simple mistake I'm making but I'm a bit lost here.

Here is my script:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing
import random


class RandomM(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    This is an example algorithm that takes a vector layer and
    creates a new identical one.

    It is meant to be used as an example of how to create your own
    algorithms and explain methods and variables used to do it. An
    algorithm like this will be available in all elements, and there
    is not need for additional work.

    All Processing algorithms should extend the QgsProcessingAlgorithm
    class.
    """

    # Constants used to refer to parameters and outputs. They will be
    # used when calling the algorithm from another algorithm, or when
    # calling from the QGIS console.

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return RandomM()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the algorithm name, used for identifying the algorithm. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The name should be unique within each provider. Names should contain
        lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'randomm'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name, which should be used for any
        user-visible display of the algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Random M')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to. This string
        should be localised.
        """
        return self.tr('M scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs to. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The group id should be unique within each provider. Group id should
        contain lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'mscripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short helper string for the algorithm. This string
        should provide a basic description about what the algorithm does and the
        parameters and outputs associated with it..
        """
        return self.tr("Creates Random M values")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
            )
        )

        # We add a feature sink in which to store our processed features (this
        # usually takes the form of a newly created vector layer when the
        # algorithm is run in QGIS).
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """

        # To run another Processing algorithm as part of this algorithm, you can use
        # processing.run(...). Make sure you pass the current context and feedback
        # to processing.run to ensure that all temporary layer outputs are available
        # to the executed algorithm, and that the executed algorithm can send feedback
        # reports to the user (and correctly handle cancellation and progress reports!)
        
        outputFile = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)
        target_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )
        for feature in target_layer.getFeatures():
            feedback.pushInfo('Processing feature {0}'.format(feature.id()))
            geom = feature.geometry()
            for part in geom.parts():
                for p in part.vertices():
                    feedback.pushInfo('p.m(): {}'.format(p.m()))
                    p.setM(random.uniform(0.001, 0.002))
                    feedback.pushInfo('p.m(): {}'.format(p.m()))
        
        buffered_layer = processing.run("native:bufferbym", {
            'INPUT': target_layer,
            'SEGMENTS': 16,
            'OUTPUT': outputFile
        }, is_child_algorithm=True, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
        
        # Return the results of the algorithm. In this case our only result is
        # the feature sink which contains the processed features, but some
        # algorithms may return multiple feature sinks, calculated numeric
        # statistics, etc. These should all be included in the returned
        # dictionary, with keys matching the feature corresponding parameter
        # or output names.
        return {self.OUTPUT: buffered_layer}
```

feedback while the for loop is running shows updated M values, but the output doesn't reflect the randomly assigned m-value, only the original ones.

Comment: It depends on what edit method you are trying to do. What method are you looking for? Perhaps you could select the vertices or lines that you want to edit. Some tools will perform only on the selected features.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want to do?

Comment: I want to create a variable width buffer using the M values, which QGIS has a tool for, but I'd like to be able to programatically alter the M values along a line to adjust the buffer. The lines have thousands of vertices, so manual editing is not feasible.

Comment: Consider adding sample data to the question eg a sample set of vertices (in a layer), and a sample set of M-values. It will be doable using PyQGIS (eg https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsPoint.html#qgis.core.QgsPoint.setM)

Comment: Added more info to the question and attempted to use setM() as you suggested.